# Как задать русскоязычный пароль для zip-файла в C#?

Tags: c#, .net, архивация, dotnetzip

Нужно задать пароль для zip-папки, при этом пароль должен содержать русские символы. Для создания zip-папки используется библиотека [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) ([Nuget-пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/)):

```
using (var zipFile = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile(Encoding.UTF8))
{
     zipFile.AlternateEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
     zipFile.AlternateEncodingUsage = Ionic.Zip.ZipOption.Always;
     zipFile.Password = "123";
     zipFile.AddFile(@"d:\orig.xls");
     zipFile.Save(@"d:\orig.zip");
}
```

Файл успешно создаётся на диске и распаковывается, однако, если задать пароль с русскими символами, например `zipFile.Password = "ййй";`, то при распаковывании архива получаю ошибку, которая говорит о том, что пароль неверный. Что делать?

Comment: А как вы распаковываете архив?

Comment: Мне кажется вопрос состоит из 2-х частей. 1.Поддерживает ли zip русскоязычный пароль. (если да, то скорее всего он в UTF-8 кодировке, но может и в UNICODE). 2. Какая библиотека поддерживает паковку с русскоязычным паролем. И как P.S. NET4 поддерживает zip-сжатие (не доп-пакеты, а сам фреймфорк), NET2 - поддерживает Deflate сжатие, на базе которого вероятно можно сделать zip-архив.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно посмотреть и перепробовать библиотеки zip. Желательно поближе к стандартным.

Comment: Боюсь вам прийдётся пересмотреть ещё другие библиотеки (писатели перечисленых не знали о русском). Я бы посмотрел в сторону ActiveX на ShellApplication (но незнаю поддерживает ли она пароль).  А лучше на `System.IO.Compression` из NET4 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/53a468a2-0135-4040-9e7b-7c113b9f57ee/extract-zip-or-rar-file-using-c-netframework-40?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: А вы пробовали [конструктор с кодировкой](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/f2fda0ce-f080-37d5-8228-f1e1e8ab08b7.htm)?

Comment: [Документация говорит](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/2418e26f-685a-b5b8-5c79-984d5b8da61a.htm), что `UseUnicodeAsNecessary` использовать не надо, а вместо него нужно [`AlternateEncoding`](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/8a1c42ee-eeb8-22e6-c455-4167c731ade6.htm) и [`AlternateEncodingUsage`](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/html/0589ce9d-e68b-97c2-2b00-0b3d46f05a65.htm).

Comment: @VladD, обновил вопрос. Попробовал - не помогает.

Comment: @nick_n_a, `System.IO.Compression` не поддерживает паролирование.

Answer (score 1):

Ну очевидно, что проблема в кодировке русского пароля. Надо задавать явную кодировку пароля, например Win-1251 (подозреваю, что распаковку пытаетесь делать стандартным zip'ом в среде OC Windows.

Comment: Самый простой - исходники должны быть в кодировке Win-1251 - в разных IDE это задается по разному. Поройтесь в настройках редактора IDE

Comment: пересохранил исходник в ANSI - ничего не изменилось.

Comment: причем тут ANSI? Вам нужен Win-1251

Comment: Пардон :) Копаюсь в настройках VS2015, не могу найти что-нибудь подобное.

Comment: по умолчанию обычно UTF-8, как поменять [посмотрите здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840065/how-to-change-source-file-encoding-in-csharp-project-visual-studio-msbuild-ma)

Comment: пересохранение не помогло, ровно как и явная конвертация строки с паролем в Win-1251 при помощи метода `Encoding.Convert(...)`.